# grails, jquery chosen multiselection with g:select

Tags: jquery, grails, select

I'm using the jquery chosen plugin for a multiselect in conjunction with the grails `<g:select>`. It should be a selector for multiple users which are defined in the domain class via `has many = [users: User]`. It works in most cases pretty good but if for example 3 users are selected and I want to delete just one, nothing happens. If i delete 2 it updates correctly. If nothing is selected I can add all users one by one and it works.

That is my code in the gsp:

```
<g:select id="pickUsers" name="users" from="${usermanagement.User.list()}" multiple="true" optionKey="id" value="${projectInstance?.users*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pickUsers').chosen({width: "25%",
                            no_results_text: "Keine Ergebnisse für",
                            placeholder_text_multiple: "Mitarbeiter suchen..."})
    $('#pickUsers').trigger("chosen:updated")
    $('#pickUsers').on('change', function() {
        var currentValues = $('#pickUsers').chosen().val();
        if (currentValues == null) {
            $("#pickUsers").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
        }
    });
</script>
```

developer tools:

```
_method:PUT
version:8
users:3
users:2
_action_update:Aktualisieren
```

this is showing the right selection but apparently its not updating it, it still shows all 3 users. In grails I just used `has many` and didn't change anything.

I just logged the incoming users in the controllers update method:

all three users are set: `users: [leader, test, me]`
delete test user in view: `users: [leader, me, leader, test]`

Like I mentioned this just happens if I delete **ONE** user, if I delete 2 all works

EDIT: potential "fix" in controller:

```
@Transactional
    def update(Project projectInstance) {
        if (projectInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        //get users from jquery users-picker in view
        def usersPicker = params.users

        //clear users set of incoming instance
        if(projectInstance.users !=  null){
            projectInstance.users.clear()
        }

        //add users from picker in view to set
        for (user in usersPicker){

            def tempUser = User.get(user)
            projectInstance.users.add(tempUser)
        }

        if (projectInstance.hasErrors()) {
            respond projectInstance.errors, view:'edit'
            return
        }

        projectInstance.save flush:true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [
                    message(code: 'Project.label', default: 'Project'),
                    projectInstance.id
                ])
                redirect projectInstance
            }
            '*'{ respond projectInstance, [status: OK] }
        }
    }
```

the above mentioned logs are directly from the incoming instance in the update method. I need to clear the users set and bind the users from `currentValues` (javascript in view) to the instance.

Comment: have a look at the details of the http request (using developer console) to see if the problem is on the front or the back end.

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant information

Comment: Can you show us your method "Aktualisieren"?'

Comment: Its just the standard grails update function in the controller. I added there a few lines which solved the problem, but its not very pretty. I edit them into my initial post